How to test wireframes in Figma?
I am designing some wireframes in Figma and I have been tasked with investigating on how we can test our wireframes, is there a way to test wireframes in Figma?

You can create wireframes in frames, like you would add a regular design, and make 'wireframe' buttons clickable in the prototype tab.
https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040314193-Guide-to-prototyping-in-Figma

Use Figma’s prototyping features to link different frames and create a flow. Add interactivity (like button clicks and page transitions) to simulate the user journey.
And Share the prototype link with testers or stakeholders, allowing them to interact with the wireframes as though they were using a real product.
Plugins like User Testing, Maze, or Lookback integrate with Figma to facilitate user testing directly. They can capture user behavior, clicks, and responses, providing insights into usability and potential areas of confusion.
Use Figma’s comments feature to gather feedback. Ask testers to leave comments directly on the wireframes, detailing any issues or confusing elements they encounter. This works well for asynchronous feedback.
Remote Usability Testing:
Use tools like Maze or Useberry, which connect to Figma prototypes and allow you to set up specific tasks. These platforms collect analytics on click paths, task completion rates, and drop-off points, giving quantitative insights into the wireframe’s usability.
Hope this will be helpful.
